# Vue Filter one array by an other array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good morning, I have an array that looks like this:

```json
[
   {
      "firstname": "John"
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "delegatesid":38
   },
   {
      "firstname": "Jane"
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "delegatesid":5
   },
....
```

Let's just call it `itemsDelegates`. And then I have this one:

```json
[
   {
      "id":2,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":38,
      "role":0,
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":45,
      "role":0,
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":50,
      "role":0,
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":5,
      "role":0,
   }
]
```

Now let's call this `addressvisibility`. Now I'm trying to remove from `itemsDelegates` all entries that are already in `addressvisibility`. I tried the following approach:

```js
            this.itemsDelegates = response.data
            var deletgates = this.itemsDelegates
            this.items.addressvisibility.forEach(function(element){
              deletgates.filter(element, (obj) => {
                return obj.delegatesid != element.delegatesid
              })
            });
```

Nevertheless, `itemsDelegates` still contains all entries. Where is my thinking error here?

Comment: Don't pass element into filter, just the callback fct. Element is already available inside. Also assign the filter return value to something. Filter is creating a new Array which should hold your filtered entries. Edit: And don't copy solutions below. Continue with your own. Make it work and learn. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` returns a new array that only contains items matching the given criteria. It does not filter the array in-place. The simplest answer is to reassign the value of the array such that `delegates = delegates.filter(...)`.

However, you could also combine `addressvisibility.some` and `delegates.filter`:

```js
delegates = delegates.filter(delegate =>
    this.items.addressvisibility.some(av => av.delegatesid === delegate.delegatesid) === false
);
```

That will filter out any items in `delegates` where there are `some` (one or more) in `addressvisibility` where `delegatesid` matches.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. But do ensure that your array objects are having the appropriate commas and are structured well. I saw some of them are missing commas.

```
let a = [
   {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "delegatesid":38
   },
   {
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "delegatesid":5
   }]


let b = [
   {
      "id":2,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":38,
      "role":0,
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":45,
      "role":0,
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "addressesid":209411,
      "delegatesid":50,
      "role":0,
   },
];


let ans = a.filter((x) => {
 let bIndex = b.findIndex((it) =>{
   return it.delegatesid == x.delegatesid;
 });
  if(bIndex == -1) return true;
  return false;
});

console.log(ans);
```

I am filtering the first array based on the condition that the second array has a matching delegate id or not using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).